# How to cite Terms of Use in APA 7?

Tags: style, citations, apa

I'm trying to find out how to cite the Terms of Use of an app (BeReal) - I found [this answer](https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/9060/57025) to a similar question, but I wasn't sure if this was still accurate to APA 7. I apologize if this has been asked more recently.

Comment: How are the terms of use published - within the app, or on a web page or elsewhere? Googling should tell you how to cite an app.

Comment: The terms can be found online [here](https://bere.al/en/terms) - I wasn't sure if citing the app itself was adequate, but I suppose that works.